# Doing exp math in R/Google Earth Engine (rgee)

Tags: r, google-earth-engine, rstudio

Is this the correct syntax in R-Studio for rgee (Google Earth Engine) for the following equation?

`y=0.7*e^(4.1*x)` where x is represented by "data" below.

```
y<-data$multiply(4.1)$exp()$multiply(0.7)
```

I also tried...

```
calcResult<-function(image) {
  return(image$exp(image$multiply(4.1))$multiply(0.7))
}
 y<-calcResult(data)
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Does it do anything? Can you check the values in a couple of pixels to see if it works?

Comment: I ended up splitting the equation into three commands. ```y<-x$multiply(4.1)```
Then, ```y<-y$exp()``` and a third line, ```y<-y$multiply(0.7)$rename('result')```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up splitting the equation into three commands.

`y<-x$multiply(4.1)`

Then,

`y<-y$exp()`

and a third line,

`y<-y$multiply(0.7)$rename('result')`